# Thumbnails Image Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here This is what I am trying. On Click of each thumbnail I have to display the Larger Image. I need some help so that I can know my issue why the click method is not working fine for me.

**Thumbs Part HTML**

```
<div class="ScreenShot" id="__control0" data--ui="__control0">
<div id="thumbs" data--ui="thumbs" class="UiHLayout UiHLayoutNoWrap">
<div class="UiHLayoutChildWrapper">
<div id="__set0" data--ui="__set0" class="UiUx3DS">
<div id="__set0-items">
<div id="__view0" data--ui="__view0" class="UiUx3DSSV">
<div class="UiUx3DSSVFlow UiUx3DSSVItem UiUx3DSSVSelected" id="__item0-__set0-0" data--ui="__item0-__set0-0">
<div id="__layout0-0" data--ui="__layout0-0" class="uiVlt">
<div class="uiVltCell">
<img id="__image0-0" data--ui="__image0-0" src="images/image_01_thumb.jpg" class="UiImg" role="presentation" alt="" tabindex="-1">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="UiUx3DSSVFlow UiUx3DSSVItem" id="__item0-__set0-1" data--ui="__item0-__set0-1">
<div id="__layout0-1" data--ui="__layout0-1" class="uiVlt">
<div class="uiVltCell">
<img id="__image0-1" data--ui="__image0-1" src="images/image_02_thumb.jpg" class="UiImg" role="presentation" alt="" tabindex="-1">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="UiUx3DSSVFlow UiUx3DSSVItem" id="__item0-__set0-2" data--ui="__item0-__set0-2">
<div id="__layout0-2" data--ui="__layout0-2" class="uiVlt">
<div class="uiVltCell">
<img id="__image0-2" data--ui="__image0-2" src="images/image_03_thumb.jpg" class="UiImg" role="presentation" alt="" tabindex="-1">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Larger Images HTML**

```
<div id="panel" data--ui="panel" class="UiHLayout UiHLayoutNoWrap">
<div class="UiHLayoutChildWrapper">
<div id="__set1" data--ui="__set1" class="UiUx3DS">
<div id="__set1-items">
<div id="__view1" data--ui="__view1" class="UiUx3DSSV">
<div class="UiUx3DSSVFlow UiUx3DSSVItem UiUx3DSSVSelected" id="__item1-__set1-0" data--ui="__item1-__set1-0">
<div id="__layout1-0" data--ui="__layout1-0" class="uiVlt">
<div class="uiVltCell">
<img id="__image1-0" data--ui="__image1-0" src="images/image_01_large.jpg" class="UiImg" role="presentation" alt="" tabindex="-1">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="UiUx3DSSVFlow UiUx3DSSVItem" id="__item1-__set1-1" data--ui="__item1-__set1-1">
<div id="__layout1-1" data--ui="__layout1-1" class="uiVlt">
<div class="uiVltCell">
<img id="__image1-1" data--ui="__image1-1" src="images/image_02_large.jpg" class="UiImg" role="presentation" alt="" tabindex="-1">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="UiUx3DSSVFlow UiUx3DSSVItem" id="__item1-__set1-2" data--ui="__item1-__set1-2">
<div id="__layout1-2" data--ui="__layout1-2" class="uiVlt">
<div class="uiVltCell">
<img id="__image1-2" data--ui="__image1-2" src="images/image_03_large.jpg" class="UiImg" role="presentation" alt="" tabindex="-1">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$("#thumbs img").click(function(){
    $("#thumbs img.clicked").removeClass('clicked');
    $("#panel img").hide();
    $("#panel img:nth-child("+Number($(this).index()+1)+")").fadeIn();
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
});
```

Here is the demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/L7yKp/5/

On click of each thumbnail the corresponding image should be fadeIn. But here every larger image is fading In.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple working demo matching your needs: http://jsfiddle.net/D6XHt/1/

Note: It's not the same html as yours but should you push to the right direction. The technique i'ma using has one disadvantage. Without JS enabled your users will see only on big image.

**BUT** a real advantage is you will save bandwidth and page loading time if you have many images. This is because every big image will load only if the user clicks a thumbnail.

Here is another working solution with all images in document.

http://jsfiddle.net/D6XHt/2/

If you want to show your Images in a fancy lightbox Popup try

- http://fancybox.net/home or
- http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox

Comment: I should use the src path to show the images, But you are showing it using its attr data-full, Can you please send a demo using src as its path

Comment: My example is using the src path to show images. Do you need to have all images placed in your document?

Comment: Yes, Onclick of each thumbnail a popup should open having larger images in it

Comment: A popup should open? You've never said it before... See update above.

Comment: If am using my HTML structure I am facing a problem onclick of each thumbnail only the first Larger image is displaying. This is the demo link http://jsfiddle.net/L7yKp/10/

Comment: Can you please help me out with the issue that I am facing, please

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/L7yKp/35/ The .index() of every Thumbnail is 0 if you are using $("#thumbs img")